# Trying to pull responses from a form

Tags: php, html

so recently I was trying to pull all of the responses when you click a button in order to show you what you placed. Using the following line inside of a method in PHP I attempted to pull this and relay the information. As of such its not working for me.

**PHP METHOD**

```
function results(){
    $responses = $_POST['test'];
    foreach($responses as $response){
      print "".$response." <br />";
    }
}
```

**FORM TAG**

```
<form id="test" name="test">
```

**BUTTON**

```
  <button type="button" onclick="results()">
    Complete
  </button>
```

Comment: You need to send an AJAX request to that PHP code.

Comment: Can you also show your inputs? chris is right, you cant call a php function with onlick attribute on a button.

Answer (score 0):

your Post keys will bind to your parameters within your form, not the form itself so

**HTML**

```
<form id="test" name="test">
    <input type="text" name="somfield" />
    <button type="button" onclick="results()"> Complete </button>
</form>
```

Would be access like

**PHP**

```
function results(){
    $response = $_POST['someField'];
}
```

So to do what you would like just loop all the keys of the POST

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    print "$name : $value<br>";
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: I understand the concept of this but i'm still not getting anything show up.

Comment: again, an onclick attribute only calls javascript functions; not PHP.

Comment: Gokigooooks is correct if you are trying to run the php function that way. The php code is executed server side so you have to send the post. Look at his answer above and note how he is posting the form back to the server to regenerate the page with the output.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a PHP function with an onlick attribute. Though you can do this as a work around.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       function results(){
          $somevar =  $_POST['sometext'];

       } 
   }
```

and on your html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    sometext : <input type="text" name="sometext" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Leaving your action attribute blank will make the page load itself upon submitting while setting the input submit  button. activating the isset condition.

**and** lastly, I dont know how you did your inputs, but I see your using a loop for getting the results. As far as I know, no html input fields has an array input. maybe you can do this.

```
<input type="text" name="response1">
<input type="text" name="response2">
<input type="text" name="response3">
<input type="text" name="response4">
```

and to iterate through this.

```
<?
    for($i=1;$i>4;$i++)
    {

      $response = "response".$i;
      echo $_POST[$response];
    }
?>
```